# How to use sfdx force:data:bulk:upsert on an object without an external ID?

Tags: salesforcedx, upsert, externalid

I have a custom object (CustomObject__c) which is a child of another custom object. I want to import some records (CSV files) of CustomObject__c via SFDX (`force:data:bulk:upsert`).

These are the custom fields of the CustomObject__c

- Name (Text (80))
- Parent_Object__c (Master-Detail)
- Locale__c (Lookup)

The problem is, CustomObject__c does not have any external ID (I cannot assign any relationship field to become the external ID) and `sfdx force:data:bulk:upsert` needs an external ID.

I know there are Data Loader and Data Import, but I want to create a script and automate the process of creating a new scratch org later. I also know that there is `force:data:tree:import` but it requires JSON format and what we have right now is CSV.

Is there any workaround for this?

**EDIT:**

I have imported the parent object records before executing this command.

**Command:**

```
sfdx force:data:bulk:upsert -s CustomObject__c -f csv/CustomObject.csv -i Id
```

**CustomObject.csv:**

```
Parent_Object__c,Name,Locale__c
tv,TV,de_DE
tv,TV,en_US
phone,Phone,en_US
phone,Handy,de_DE
car,Car,en_US
car,Auto,de_DE
```

**Result:**

```
=== Batch Status
jobId:                   7501X000001ABCDE
state:                   Completed
createdDate:             2019-08-06T13:29:37.000Z
systemModstamp:          2019-08-06T13:29:46.000Z
numberRecordsProcessed:  6
numberRecordsFailed:     6
totalProcessingTime:     91
apiActiveProcessingTime: 2
apexProcessingTime:      0
```

**Error:**

```
=== Upsert errors
MALFORMED_ID:Parent Object: id value of incorrect type: tv:Parent_Object__c --
MALFORMED_ID:Parent Object: id value of incorrect type: tv:Parent_Object__c --
MALFORMED_ID:Parent Object: id value of incorrect type: phone:Parent_Object__c --
MALFORMED_ID:Parent Object: id value of incorrect type: phone:Parent_Object__c --
MALFORMED_ID:Parent Object: id value of incorrect type: car:Parent_Object__c --
MALFORMED_ID:Parent Object: id value of incorrect type: car:Parent_Object__c --
```

EDIT 2:

**CustomObject_rev1.csv**

```
Child_relationship_Name__r.Code__c,Name,Locale__c
tv,TV,de_DE
tv,TV,en_US
phone,Phone,en_US
phone,Handy,de_DE
car,Car,en_US
car,Auto,de_DE
```

I got an Error:

> ERROR running force:data:bulk:upsert:  InvalidBatch : Unable to find
>   relationship: Child_relationship_Name__r

Comment: Have you tried using Id as external ID field? The documentation uses it in an example: `$ sfdx force:data:bulk:upsert -s MyObject__c -f ./path/to/file.csv -i Id -w 2` https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_data.htm

Comment: @Folkert Thanks for pointing that out. I've just tried it, unfortunately the import is still failed. I have added additional information

Comment: Ah, you also want to use external id fields on the parent objects to fill the relation, you'll need to adjust the column headers and reference the external id fields on those objects like `Locale__r.ExtneralId__c', see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/datafiles_csv_rel_field_header_row.htm

Comment: @Folkert Thanks for the info. I have an external ID on my parent object (it is called Code__c). I have changed the csv (added on edit) and it still does not work.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct relation name? You need to enter the lookup field name, not the name of the relation going down from the parent.

Comment: @Folkert I took the **Child Relationship Name** from Parent_Object__c (Master-Detail) field from the CustomObject__c object. Are there any other relation name?

Comment: @Folkert So I have changed the CSV header to: `Parent_Object__r.Code__c,Name,Locale__c`. Now I got a different error: `MALFORMED_ID:Locale: id value of incorrect type: de_DE:Locale__c --`. But at least I think the Parent_Object__c works now.

Comment: Well, the same principle applies to the Locale__c object as well, so try changing that to Locale__r.ExternalIdFieldOnThatObject__c

Comment: @Folkert Thank you! That solves the issue! Could you please post your first comment (and second comment too?) as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: There needs to be a sfdx force:data:bulk:insert command which does not require an external id.   I think this is just a clear omission.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using Id as external ID field?

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_data.htm) uses it in an example:
 `$ sfdx force:data:bulk:upsert -s MyObject__c -f ./path/to/file.csv -i Id -w 2`

In addition to that, if you want to use external ids from related object like you do in your example, [you need to reference them](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/datafiles_csv_rel_field_header_row.htm) in the csv column headers:

```
Parent_Object__r.ExternalIdField__c,Name,Locale__r.AnotherExternalIdField__c
tv,TV,de_DE
tv,TV,en_US
phone,Phone,en_US
phone,Handy,de_DE
car,Car,en_US
car,Auto,de_DE
```

Comment: Using Id as external ID field does indeed work

Answer (score 4):

I know of at least three options for you.

`sfdx force:data:tree:import` should work fine for your situation if you're willing to switch to JSON format for your data storage. The easiest way to do this would be to load up your sample data in an org and retrieve it using `sfdx force:data:tree:export`, rather than generating the data by hand.

If you really want to stick with CSV format, you can use [Amaxa](https://gitlab.com/davidmreed/amaxa) to load multiple objects with relationships. I wrote Amaxa for this specific use case, and its native storage format is CSV. It is free and open source. You'd use a simple YAML definition file like this:

```
version: 1
operation:
    -
        sobject: Parent_Object__c
        fields:
            - Id
            - Name
        extract:
            all: True
    -
        sobject: Custom_Object__c
        fields:
            - Id
            - Name
            - Locale__c
            - Parent_Object__c
        extract:
            descendents: True
```

That would load up `Parent_Object__c` records from `Parent_Object__c.csv`, then load `Custom_Object__c` records from `Custom_Object__c.csv` and map `Parent_Object__c` Ids to preserve relationships.

Another option if you're willing to switch formats is Salesforce.org's [CumulusCI (CCI)](https://github.com/SFDO-Tooling/CumulusCI/) continuous integration/orchestration tool, which is also free and open source.

CCI works with Salesforce DX and provides configurable [bulk data](https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bulk_data.html) load and extract tasks, which use a simple YAML mapping format to convert data to and from a SQLite data store.

The nice thing about CCI is that it works as part of an end-to-end scratch org build automation process that you can define in markup and run repeatably. (Disclaimer: I am on the team that builds CCI at Salesforce.org).